# Unable to upload image with laravel after fetch

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I am trying to upload an image from my react native project using laravel as my backend framework.

This is the data I send :[image]
I receive a warning that my network request failed.

Here is my backend code :

```
 public function upload(Request $request)
  {

    $image = $request->get('data');
    $name = 'Sup';
    Image::make($request->get('data'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);




    $fileupload = new Fileupload();
    $fileupload->filename=$name;
    $fileupload->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success']);

 }
```

Comment: did you try on postman?

Comment: no , i haven't used postman , so i don't know how to use it

Comment: usually the network request fail because your server may not running. pls check and confirm

Comment: my server is running 100% , and also my fetch method is 100% correct. So i am assuming , maybe i my laravel code that i posted has some issues.Maybe i don't receive the data i should receive ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a function, you can try it!

Please **change the path** before doing anything else (this is the code used to upload one - multiple files at once)

```
public function uploadImage (Request $request) {
        $files = $request->file('images');
        $fileText = '';
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg');
            $validator = Validator::make(array('file' => $file), $rules);
            if($validator->passes()){
                $destinationPath = 'storage/images/';
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $unique_name = md5($filename. time()).$filename;
                $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $unique_name);
                $fileText .= url('storage/images/' . $unique_name) . '|';
            }
        }
        return rtrim($fileText, '|');
    }
```

Comment: thanks mate , but still it doesn't work for me.Can you specify for me , what data does $request receive?I mean does it receive the full Request and i have to take the attribute data , or is it something else?